# Why didn't Microsoft make a deep cloning function in the BCL?

Tags: c#, deep-copy

They obviously used it somewhere, why didn't they give as such a method?
(Even if they didn't use it anywhere, they still could have given us such a method).

Answer (score 9):

Probably because a naïve implementation of deep cloning is **more dangerous than helpful**. Without extreme care, one could easily accidentally clone huge chunks of their entire application heap - including things which should not be cloned. In practice, deep cloning is usually implementation specific - the cloner knows what it's looking for and only follows those paths.

There's also Eric Lippert's classic answer - they didn't provide it because **[adding simple things is hard.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx)**

Comment: Not only would a naive implementation copy an excessive amount of redundant data.  It would in many cases be semantically wrong.  If `Foo` holds a reference-type field `Bar` which encapsulates the *identity* of its target, rather than the mutable state thereof, a correct clone of `Foo` (call the clone `Moo`) must copy that field verbatim; making `Moo.Bar` point to a copy of `Foo.Bar`'s target would not just be inefficient--it would be semantically *wrong*, since operations on `Moo.Bar` would not affect the object whose *identity* had been encapsulated in `Foo.Bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Because each object would have a different deep-clone behavior; some objects would be [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)s and not cloneable at all, and the notion of "deep-clone" isn't so obvious for every object.

Answer (score 1):

Deep copying (or cloning) is in general not easy because classes generally contain references to other classes that may be difficult to represent as a "sequential memory block" and thus copy. That's why it's usually done by serializing/deserializing the object: that way you can control what and how is actually copied.

If you are interested to experience this first-hand you can try and write your own serializer. It will be a very interesting projects and you'll realize many of the subtle -and not so subtle- problems hidden behind this apparently simple topic.

Answer (score 0):

The native behavior of BinaryFormatter is in fact a deep clone. There has been an IClonable interface since .NET 1.0, but it has been obsoleted and MS advises AGAINST implementing this interface, specifically because of the concern that a consumer does not necessarily know whether the IClonable implementation performs a deep or shallow clone. Deep cloning is dangerous.

Comment: "Deep cloning is dangerous." - With great power comes great responsibility!

Answer (score 0):

Because deep-cloning is serious enough to warrant several namespaces.  See Serialization.